# How can I make pasting work like yanking?

Tags: command-line, clipboard, emacs, dash-shell

If I press ctrl+y (yank) in some programs, then the program will output what's in the clipboard to the current selected screen area. But why doesn't it work from the terminal? I would like a more convenient way to run commands instead of copypasting them with the mouse. yanking would be more convenient, so is it possible to configure the shell to paste the clipboard if I press ctrl+y, just like emacs does?

Answer (score 1):

`emacs` uses buffer for everything and the things like kill (`C-w`) - yank (`C-y`) or copy (`M-w`) - yank (`C-y`) are `emacs` controlled properties (other editors (e.g. `vi`) support these sort of behaviors too).

But the terminal behaves differently; it runs a shell inside and it does not contain the mentioned concepts. It does have some keyboard shortcuts to perform some defined actions though; Copy-Paste is one of those, you can copy a section of terminal using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.